# Align columns on table with fixed header

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-table

I search anything that can help me about this, but nothing help me.

I copied here (http://jsfiddle.net/YUyyZ/) the code. The error is that the fixed row (thead) isn't aligned to the rest of the table (tbody).

What can I do? Thanks a lot.

HTML:

```
<table id=ff witdh=100 style=position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0; border=1 cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0>

  <thead>
   <th align='center'> id </th>
   <th align='center'> aaaaaaa </th>
   <th align='center'> asdasdad </th>
   <th align='center'> adasd </th>
   <th align='center'> herh4e45h </th>
   <th align='center'> h4eh4ehg4 </th>
   <th align='center'> gh4gh4ege </th>
   <th align='center'> ehtre </th>
   <th align='center'> brebebes </th>
   <th align='center'> berberb </th>
   <th align='center'> erberberb </th>
   <th align='center'> erberdsber </th>
  <thead><tbody>
 <tr>
     <td width=100 align='center'> id </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 1 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 2 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 3 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 4 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 5 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 6 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 7 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 8 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 9 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 0 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 11 </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
     <td width=100 align='center'> id </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 1 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 2 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 3 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 4 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 5 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 6 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 7 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 8 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 9 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 0 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 11 </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
     <td width=100 align='center'> id </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 1 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 2 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 3 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 4 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 5 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 6 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 7 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 8 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 9 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 0 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 11 </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
     <td width=100 align='center'> id </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 1 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 2 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 3 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 4 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 5 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 6 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 7 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 8 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 9 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 0 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 11 </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
     <td width=100 align='center'> id </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 1 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 2 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 3 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 4 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 5 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 6 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 7 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 8 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 9 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 0 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 11 </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
     <td width=100 align='center'> id </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 1 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 2 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 3 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 4 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 5 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 6 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 7 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 8 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 9 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 0 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 11 </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
     <td width=100 align='center'> id </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 1 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 2 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 3 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 4 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 5 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 6 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 7 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 8 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 9 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 0 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 11 </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
     <td width=100 align='center'> id </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 1 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 2 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 3 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 4 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 5 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 6 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 7 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 8 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 9 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 0 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 11 </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
     <td width=100 align='center'> id </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 1 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 2 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 3 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 4 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 5 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 6 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 7 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 8 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 9 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 0 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 11 </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
     <td width=100 align='center'> id </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 1 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 2 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 3 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 4 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 5 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 6 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 7 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 8 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 9 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 0 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 11 </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
     <td width=100 align='center'> id </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 1 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 2 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 3 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 4 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 5 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 6 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 7 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 8 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 9 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 0 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 11 </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
     <td width=100 align='center'> id </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 1 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 2 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 3 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 4 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 5 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 6 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 7 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 8 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 9 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 0 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 11 </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
     <td width=100 align='center'> id </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 1 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 2 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 3 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 4 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 5 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 6 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 7 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 8 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 9 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 0 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 11 </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
     <td width=100 align='center'> id </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 1 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 2 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 3 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 4 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 5 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 6 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 7 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 8 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 9 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 0 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 11 </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
     <td width=100 align='center'> id </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 1 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 2 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 3 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 4 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 5 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 6 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 7 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 8 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 9 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 0 </td>
     <td width=100 align='center'> 11 </td>
  </tr>
```

CSS:

```
table a:link {
color: #666;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration:none;
}
table a:visited {
color: #999999;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:none;
}
table a:active,
table a:hover {
color: #bd5a35;
text-decoration:underline;
}
table {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#666;
font-size:12px;
background:#eaebec;
border:#ccc 1px solid;

border-radius:3px;
border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing: 0; 

box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
}
table th {
padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
border-top:0;
border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;

background: #ededed;
}
table th:first-child {
text-align: left;
}
table tr:first-child th:first-child {
border-top-left-radius:3px;
border-left: 0;
}
table tr:first-child th:last-child {
border-top-right-radius:3px;
}
table tr {
text-align: center;
}
table td:first-child {
text-align: left;
border-left: 0;
}
table td {
padding:10px;
border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
background: #fafafa;
}
table tr:last-child td {
border-bottom:0;
}
table tr:last-child td:first-child {
border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
}
table tr:last-child td:last-child {
border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
}
table tr:hover td {
background: #f2f2f2;

}
table th, table td {
width: 160px;

}
#wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
table thead
{
position:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the ` tags. :)
Should be fixed, tested.
Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dLQ6J/

Added some jQuery:

```
var tableOffset = $("#table-1").offset().top;
var $header = $("#table-1 > thead").clone();
var $fixedHeader = $("#header-fixed").append($header);

$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    var offset = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (offset >= tableOffset && $fixedHeader.is(":hidden")) {
        $fixedHeader.show();
    }
    else if (offset < tableOffset) {
        $fixedHeader.hide();
    }
});
```

WARNING: TO RUN jQUERY ON A PAGE INCLUDE THE CODE IN `<script>` tags, don't forget to add the jQuery JS too:
Did you include the jQuery Javascript ? To run jQuery on a page you must also include this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Without the line above it won't work :)

Comment: Hi! Thanks! But your code haven't got the first row fixed. :(

Comment: Oh, you want the table content to scroll but header to stand still ?

Comment: Hi! On jsfiddle works great, but on my web, copied and pasted, not.
I saw that on Codepen (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AFkJt), and JSBin (http://jsbin.com/ogEwuLEt/1/) doesn't work... Why?

Comment: Yes, I've downloaded and put on js folder.
I've using that for colors on cells.

Comment: With your code, directly won't work anything else on my js, but I will reward it because it helps me changing other things.
Thx! :D

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, when you make the top of a table (the thead) fixed, it can have different column widths than an absolute or relatively positioned tbody or table body.

The way I've solved this in the past is by using JavaScript to find the widths of each column in the header, and set the body's widths to these values.

I'll try to put some code together.

Basically loop through each column in the header and store the widths in an array, then loop through the body and set each cell width to the appropriate column width to match the header.

in jQuery - much easier for me at least compared to plain JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table#ff thead tr th').each(function(index) {
    var thisWidth = $(this).width();
    $('table#ff tbody tr td').eq(index).css('minWidth', thisWidth);
  });
});
```

I think that should work - might need slight changes but the general idea is there.

Comment: See if the jQuery code fixes the layout problem, just added it

Comment: Hi! I tested it on my server and jsFiddle, but It doesn't work... I don't know jQuery language, so I can't edit nothing to except than copy and paste it, sorry.

Comment: Try it without the #ff after table - I think that was the id of the table?

Comment: Made a change to the width function to be the computed width, not the CSS - it should work now if you copy the new JS

Comment: Doesn't work --> http://jsfiddle.net/YUyyZ/4/

Maybe I am doing something wrong adding the jQuery...
Thanks a lot for helping me!

Comment: Okay! Working now! :D Last question, this jQuery will work even if put the table on a php file using echo "<table>.......</table>"?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes it should work fine, as jQuery will run on the client along with the generated table from PHP

Comment: I'm trying but doesn't work, I don't know why.
I don't know either if linking my page it is permitted here.
WEB --> http://htcmaniacraft.es/web/ff/list.php
CSS --> http://htcmaniacraft.es/web/ff/css/list.css
JS --> http://htcmaniacraft.es/web/ff/js/list.js

It would be better to make this a new question on StackOverflow?

Comment: Try wrapping the jQuery in:    $(document).ready(function() { ...jQuery code here... });

Comment: All works except the "name" column, is very thick :)
Also the page take a lot of time to load...

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in

`<table id=ff witdh=100 style=position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0; border=1 cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0>`

try `width=100%`.

Note that when you set an element to `position:fixed` you take it out of the flow and the percentage width is a percentage of the document not the original parent element.

Comment: Corrected the typo, but It doesn't work...

About the position:fixed, I know, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Erase the position :fixed to your thead{position: fixed}